# Flexbox flex property can't take css variable?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to use css varaible within the shorthad property flex or in flex-basis.
The main reason is to have this variable with ohters, at the top of my css stylesheet, to easy accomodate the possible changes that could appear in the future without having to search where this change as to be made in the stylesheet.

I have tried :

`flex: 1 1 var(--menuItemHeight) ;`

or :

`flex: 1 1 calc((100vh - 70px) / var(--numberOfMenuItems));`

Where: `--menuItemHeight: calc(( 100vh - 70px) / 5);`

or where: `--numberOfMenuItems: 5;`

Even declaring individualy the properties like:

`flex-grow: 1;`

`flex-shrink: 1;`

`flex-basis: var(--menuItemHeight);`

None of these work.

The only way I can have this work is not including any variable in the flex property and having the calulation made directly with in the property.

`flex: 1 1 calc((100vh - 70px) / 5);`

or

`flex-basis: calc((100vh - 70px) / 5);`

I could not find any information so far regarding this issue. Is this a limitation of flex property?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't `flex: 1 0 0;` do the trick?

Comment: No. actually ``flex: 1 1 auto`` is the closest.
But  I trying to have the menu item to have a certain height so they are spreaded over the height on a normal viewport to a certain extent but not more should vewport height be realy high.

Comment: any particular browser?

Comment: No not any. I tried Chrome, Firefox, Edge all the same.

Comment: Can you demo this **not** working as it seems to work for me. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qBBEWvz

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D.
I just realized that I forgot to put the " : " just before the root declaration!

Answer (score 0):

D'OH!
Just realized I forgot to put the ":" just before the root declaration!
It work now!

Also I would like to add, that after some thinking, unless you need a height to the item for some design purpose, min-height would do the thing as well.
The calc in this use case is irrelevant, flex does it for you, that’s what it’s meant to!